# Thinking in Redux

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, redux, flux

Im trying to understand redux while designing a sample App. Im confused with the concept of state vs data model.

Note: Im not using Reactjs.

**Background of the Sample App.**

2 tabular grids:

Grid A: List of members on my website.

Grid B: List of all orders by a member, selected in Grid A.

- So the end-user of this app, can select only 1 member at a time from Grid A at a time.
- The end user can also enter name of user in Grid A and my backend service will return the details for this member (for grid A) & all their past orders(Grid B).

**Redux Questions**

1. My backend service knows nothing about the order in which I list items in Grid A or B. Who should maintain order of items in the Grid? Is it responsibility of the store or the component?
2. Who maintains which member is clicked in Grid A? ? My backend service, returns me all the members and all their orders. It knowns nothing about the member that is selected on the UI.

Is it good practice, to have components keep this information and then augment the UI, whenever it refreshes from the data it gets from the store?

Answer (score 0):

Redux is made to save your current app state. But how to show it is up to your components.

1. Actually it depends on an app. There are apps with a lot of similar tables and there are component libraries where sorting logic is handled inside the component. But if all your app is based on a few tables it makes sense to add to the store a property that indicates how your table should be sorted, something like: `membersSortingType: [asc, desc, none]`. And then you pass `members` and `membersSortingType` to a function which does the sorting and returns a new `membersList` which then can be passed to your component.
2. The same is here, when you click an item you can save it to the store like: `currentMember: id`, and to get data that should be rendered in your component you just pass your member id and all the orders to a function that will do some filtering. So any time you select a new member everything is automatically updated.